# Adding key value pair to a dictionary list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to add a third child to the below dictionary:

```
person = {'Name':'Jane', 'Age':32, 'Allergies':
         [{'Allergen':'Dust'}, 
          {'Allergen':'Feathers'}, 
          {'Allergen':'Strawberries'}],
         'Children':
         [{'Name':'Ben', 'Age': 6}, {'Name':'Elly', 'Age': 8}]}

print(person)
```

`{'Name': 'Jane', 'Age': 32, 'Allergies': [{'Allergen': 'Dust'}, {'Allergen': 'Feathers'}, {'Allergen': 'Strawberries'}], 'Children': [{'Name': 'Ben', 'Age': 6}, {'Name': 'Elly', 'Age': 8}]}`

When I try update `person.update('Children': [{'Name':'Hanna', 'Age':0}])`
it replaces all children with just that one? Nothing else works either... Any suggestions?

Comment: That update code is not valid. Did you forget the curly braces? i.e. `person.update({...})`? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @wjandrea: Alternatively, `person.update(Children=[{'Name':'Hanna', 'Age':0}])` (`dict.update` accepts `**kwargs` as well as a raw `dict` or an iterable of pairs). Though in either case, it would *replace* the value for `'Children'`, not append to it.

Answer (score 2):

The `person` dictionary does not know that the `Allergies` and `Children` are lists, so you need to use the lists' methods to append things to that specific list.

```
person["Allergies"].append({"Allergen": "gluten"})
# or
person["Children"].append({"name":"Hannah", "age": 0})
```